# git add can not work

Tags: git, github

Excuse I try to push my file to github but I found error
I will tell you about I did

step 1 : I go to window 10 desktop and right click choose new folder and rename that folder is "python3"

step 2 : I coding in notepad++ and save as name "connect.py" (I choose all file) and save

step 3 : I open cmd

step 4 : I use command "cd c:/users/xxxx/desktop/python3"

step 5 : I use command "git init" and result is "Reinitialised existing Git repository in c:/users/xxxx/desktop/python3/.git "

step 6 : I use command "git add ." and I got nothing . Normally the result will show file's name that add or show something that not error (I'm not sure since " Normally the result .... ")

step 7 : I use command "git commit -m "first commit" " and the result is "On branch master    nothing to commit,working directory clean"

I think the issue start at " git add . " 
but I don't know how to solve it.

thank you for your answer

Sorry about my english skill.

Comment: what does git status show?

Comment: Are you sure you are saving connect.py in the python3 folder? What does `git status` show?

Comment: I use git status ,it show "Nothing to commit,Working directory clean". And my  file saved in that folder (python3)

Comment: `Reinitialised`, you sure you're not copying an existing file into this folder that your **existing** git repository already knows about?

Answer (score 2):

You're working in the wrong folder.

You said you created the folder brand new in step 1, but in step 5 Git says it's `Reinitialised existing Git repository`. If there's already a Git repository there it can't be the right folder.

Verify you're in the right folder in Cmd. Run `dir` to look at its contents.

Since you typed in the path to the folder it's possible you got it wrong.  I believe if you right click on a folder there will be an option to open it in Cmd or at least copy the path. Use that to get to the folder in Cmd.

Comment: I use dir the result show me about how many file stored there and show file's name "connect.py"

Comment: "Reinitialised"  I do git init many times because first time i can't do "git add" so I do it again and that is not solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can solved this problem

I remove dir .git  in that folder and git init again

Thank you very much :D